# Blender 2.78a force field not affecting particles

Tags: particles, physics

I have a particle system and I want them to move to the side using a Wind force field. Thing is, none of the force fields do anything in my scene. I looked for the issue online but no matter what I changed, no luck. How to set up one to actually work?

Comment: are the force field and the particles on the same display layer? For simulation influence, this matters. By the way, Blender 2.89 should come out approximately end of 2019, if they stick to their release cycle. Current is 2.78a

Comment: Thanks, I messed up the numbers. Dark in here :D
I have a box and it has a particles system and a force field on it.

Comment: What is the strength of your field? The default 1 is a rather subtle effect.

Comment: Cranked it up to even a million and tried in between of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your particle system to be affected by a force field, add a separate force field object (or alternatively enable force field physics on any other object), and also check its strength setting in its physics panel as the default strength of 1 is a rather subtle effect. Also in the case of a "Wind" force, check its direction, because by default it might be vertical, and the effect might look like gravity. Simply rotate the object with the wind physics to change the direction.

If you enable the force field settings on the particle system itself, it will not have the effect you want: these are used if you want your particles to affect other dynamic objects, such as other particle systems. You can check "Self Affect" to affect itself, but this is still not what you want.

Comment: Indeed, I just had to create a separate one. All the help appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

one of the main reasons the particle system not affected is probably that your force fields and the particle system  do not share the same layer.